# share filtered resources with other Maven modules

Tags: java, maven, filter, resources, multi-module

I have another maven structural problem... =/

a sample project with 3 different modules:

CONFIG (contains all configurations files)

DAO (depends on CONFIG)

SERVICE (depends on DAO and CONFIG)

The CONFIG module generates filtered resources in it's "target" folder by using the "maven-resources-plugin". How can the DAO and SERVICE modules access those filtered resources?

help help plz help =)

here's the resource filter part of the CONFIG modules POM:

```
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/resources/basic.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/context*.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CONFIG module should be producing a JAR with the filtered resources in its root.  The other modules should be able to access those resources via their classpaths, which should contain the CONFIG jar, using [ClassLoader.getResource(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29).

EDIT: after comment below.

You don't need to re-declare the Resources plugin, you simple specify the [resources in the build section](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) of the pom like this:

```
<build>

  <resources>
    <resource>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/context*.xml</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>

</build>
```

Comment: Hi! That's what i thought too... when i run target "install" on the CONFIG module the jar in the "${home}/.m2/repository" contains the unfiltered xml files. I updated my question with the configuration..

Comment: As simple as that... =) thank you! Another problem that took me hours to solve was an "CannotLoadBeanClassException" after refactoring my project with maven resource filters was caused by using maven 3.11 instead of 3.05...